# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' in googletrans

Tags: python, api, google-translate

I want to convert unknown language strings to English. For which I'm using `googletrans` python package that works along with an API to perform the desired task

So, I did following

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
translator.translate('안녕하세요.', dest='ja')
```

This gave

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9a3706f65a29> in <module>()
      1 from googletrans import Translator
      2 translator = Translator()
----> 3 translator.translate('안녕하세요.', dest='ja')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/googletrans/client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src, **kwargs)
    180 
    181         origin = text
--> 182         data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
    183 
    184         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/googletrans/client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src, override)
     76 
     77     def _translate(self, text, dest, src, override):
---> 78         token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
     79         params = utils.build_params(query=text, src=src, dest=dest,
     80                                     token=token, override=override)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py in do(self, text)
    192 
    193     def do(self, text):
--> 194         self._update()
    195         tk = self.acquire(text)
    196         return tk

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py in _update(self)
     60 
     61         # this will be the same as python code after stripping out a reserved word 'var'
---> 62         code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
     63         # unescape special ascii characters such like a \x3d(=)
     64         code = code.encode().decode('unicode-escape')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

What is causing the error? Is there any other way around to achieve the task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I have tested your scenario using your code, I also encountered the same error as seen in this screenshot.
[image: Testing using googletrans 3.0.0]

This is likely due to the old library version that you're using which is **googletrans 3.0.0**

To resolve the issue you are encountering, you must upgrade your googletrans from **3.0.0** to **4.0.0rc1**. You may use below script to upgrade your googletrans version.

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```

Please see below successful testing using **googletrans 4.0.0rc1** for your reference:
[image: Testing using googletrans 4.0.0rc1]

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the below version of googletrans;

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

This would work!